# Django 3.2 Не возвращает __str__ модели связанной через ManyToMany

Tags: python-3.x, django

Столкнулся с проблемой вывода **str** связанной модели...

Имеется несколько моделей связанных через ManyToMany:

**Модель пользователя**

```
class WSCustomer(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=255)
    
def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name
```

**Модель объекта**

```
class WSObject(models.Model):
title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=255)
customer = models.ManyToManyField(WSCustomer, related_name='own_object_customer', verbose_name='Заказчик', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'Объект: {self.title} | Заказчик: {self.customer}'
```

В результате, что в админке, что в шаблоне я получаю следующее:

```
Объект: Объект1 | Заказчик: ws_users.WSCustomer.None
```

Но если посмотреть в админке, то там ****str**** заказчика отображается нормально

---

**Нюансы**

Модели живут в разных приложениях.

У меня используется кастомная модель пользователя и модель заказчика в одном приложении **ws_users**.

```
class WSUser(AbstractBaseUser):
```

И модель заказчика:

```
class WSCustomer(models.Model):
```

В **settings.py**  базовая модель пользователя указанна **AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'ws_users.WSUser'** может ли это как-то быть связанно?
Так же если сделать отношения ManyToMany ведущее не на заказчика **WSCustomer**, а на базовую модель пользователя **WSUser** (которая также в методе ****str**** возвращает только **first_name**), то результат не меняется (((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class WSObject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=255)
    customer = models.ManyToManyField(WSCustomer, related_name='own_object_customer', verbose_name='Заказчик', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Объект: {self.title} | Заказчик: {self.customer}'
```

У вас связь `ManyToMany` , а значит там хранятся несколько объектов. Чтобы получить всех заказчиков через M2M, поменяйте на

```
def __str__(self):
    customers = ', '.join([str(x) for x in self.customer])
    return f'Объект: {self.title} | Заказчик: {customers}'
```

Если там всегда 1 объект, то

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'Объект: {self.title} | Заказчик: {self.customer.first()}'
```

А то, что Вы пытались вывести на самом деле является менеджером объектов

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо, читая Ваш ответ осознал что вместо M2M мне нужно было использовать FK...